# Parallax Android ObservableScrollView sin Toolbar

Tags: android, xml

Estoy interesado en hacer un `XML` para hacer el efecto Parallax con los items siguientes, usando una libreria de terceros llamada [ObservableScrollView](http://ksoichiro.github.io/Android-ObservableScrollView/):

```
<ImageView/>
<CardView/> //ImageView y CardView creo que deben de ir en un mismo LinearLayout, quiero que ListView tape las dos cuando haga el 'Parallax'
<ListView/> o <ObservableScrollListView/> //Nose cual necesito
```

**PREGUNTA**: Mi idea es que la `ListView` vaya ocultando, segun arrastro hacia arriba, La `ImageView` y la `CardView`, tan sencillo como eso.

El problema que tengo es que yo **no uso** `Toolbar` en toda la aplicacion ya que no me interesa, por eso recurro a esta libreria, Estoy intentando hacer el efecto de muchas maneras, pero la `CardView` no la puedo manipular bien debido a que se sobrepone encima de la `ImageView` o problemas por el estilo, tambien he conseguido resultados descoordinados, tambien añadiendo una altura a la `ListView`, se ve que limita el numero de celdas que puedo ver y si por ejemplo no pongo tamaño (a la ListView), solo me sale una celda de tamaño, la cual puedo hacer scroll y veo todo el contenido.

He seguido probando otras posibilidades pero erroneas, he estado probando en vez de `ListView`, una `ObservableScrollListView`, puede que sea algo que necesito, no estoy seguro... Os dejo el codigo a continuacion:

### **XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
android:id="@+id/observable_scrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cv"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dv"                          
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <ListView
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:id="@+id/listViewId"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>
```